# Django render admin panel with markdown fields

Tags: python, django, markdown, django-markdownx

I am having trouble with markdown on my Django application. I am writing an admin panel and want to use the markdown field. I did everything that is needed to install it:

my settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'markdownx',
]
```

models.py

```
class ProductDescription(models.Model):
    top_description = MarkdownxField(max_length=1500)
    bottom_description = MarkdownxField(max_length=1500, blank=True, null=True)
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('my_app.urls')),
    path('markdownx/', include('markdownx.urls')),
]
```

admin.py

```
class ProductDescriptionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = ProductDescription
    fields = (
        'top_description',
        'bottom_description',
     )

admin.site.register(ProductDescription, ProductDescriptionAdmin)
```

Then I executed these commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py collectstatic
python manage.py migrate
```

I'm expecting that I will be able to see a preview of my markdown field as it showed here:

https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:4800/format:webp/1*XD_0oQfMsIhmHS0MJ0LP2g.png

it looks like everything works fine except the preview, it tries to load the preview from http://localhost:8000/markdownx/markdownify/ but it receives 404 all the time

it looks like ulrs markdownx/* are not registered and I don't know why is that :( am I missing something here?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, the problem was the order of the urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('my_app.urls')),
    path('markdownx/', include('markdownx.urls')),
]
```

the empty path should be at the very end:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('markdownx/', include('markdownx.urls')),
    path('', include('my_app.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet;

```
urlpatterns = [
path('markdownx/', include('markdownx.urls')),]
```

tells Django that there is a urls.py file in the markdownx application and use that for further route resolution.

However, I do not believe that it is the case in your Django project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Naman, this line is included in URLs in my project but its not working.